# Visual Studio: используемая версия Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, python-2.x

Доброго времени суток. Интересует следующий вопрос: как понять, какую версию питона в Visual Studio ты используешь? Ту, которую устанавливал заранее && отдельно (2.7) или ту, которую предоставляет расширение Python Tools for Visual Studio?
(Используемая версия IDE: Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно посмотреть `Python` среды в разделе `Python Environments`.

Его можно открыть через `Tools->Python Tools->Python Environments`.
В окне `Python Environments` будет список доступных сред. Выделенная жирным шрифтом среда является средой по-умолчанию для проектов. На скриншоте ниже показана такая среда с надписью под списком `This is the default environment for new projects`

Для каждой среды можно посмотреть путь до её интерпретатора, выбрав её в списке сред.

[image: Python Environments]

Для каждого проекта можно выбирать среду для интерпретации.
В окне `Solution Explorer` у проектов `Python` есть пункт `Python Environments`, где можно добавить среду из установленных в разделе `Python Environments`, а также выбрать текущую среду для исполнения. Она будет выделена жирным шрифтом.

[image: Solution Explorer]